# How To Make Each Item Full Height of Container And Start Transition on Hover?

Tags: html, css, sass, hover, transition

Hello please see screenshot below. There are 4 items in the "Capabilities" and I added some transition-duration to the image and text (text moves up).

Once the mouse is in that area wether it is at the very top or bottom I want the transition to start for both the image and text.

I wasnt able to figure out how to properly make each item class the full height of the "Capabilities" ID in css.

1. How do I make each item the full height? Flexbox stetch did not work for me.
2. how do I make the transition start on hover? I am using Sass.

http://lonestarwebandgraphics.com/

[image]

HTML

```
 <div id="capabilities" class="bg-dark py-1 angle-top-right">
                <h4 class="section-title text-center">CAPABILITIES</h4>
                <h3 class="lead text-center">I DO THINGS LIKE</h3>

            <div class="items">
                <div class="item">
                    
                    <img src="img/graphic-design-icon_03.png" alt="Graphic Design">
                    <h3 class="text-center">GRAPHIC DESIGN</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="img/Web-Design-icon_01.jpg" alt="Web Design">
                    <h3 class="text-center">web design</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="img/web-development-01.png" alt="web Development">
                    <h3 class="text-center">web development</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="img/email-development.png" alt="Email Development">
                    <h3 class="text-center">Email Development</h3>
                </div>
              
            </div>
    </div>
```

SCSS

```
#capabilities {

    .items {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
        // align-items: stretch;
      
            h3 {
            color: white;
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }
       
        .item {
            
            flex: 1;

            img {
                height: 10rem;
                width: auto;
                display: block;
                margin: auto;
                margin-bottom: 2rem;
                opacity: .40;
                transition: 1s;

                    // &:hover {
                    //     opacity: 1.0;
                    // }
            }
            
            h3 {
                padding-top: 2rem;
                transition-duration: .5s;

                &:hover {
                    padding-top: 0rem;
                transition-duration: .5s;

                }
            }
        }
                .item:hover  img {
                    opacity: 1.0;
                }
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Try change `h3:hover` to `.item:hover h3`. Same for the image.

Comment: Thanks but I want to hover to start as soon as it goes over the black background for that section.

Comment: That’s why I was trying to make .items or . Item to be 100% of its parent.

Comment: The `h3` and `h4` will prevent the items from taking full height. You'll have to take them out of the flow with `position: absolute`

Comment: Are you referring to the words “capabilities” and “I do things like” ?

Comment: Yes. They take up space inside `#capabilities`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
#capabilities {

    .items {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
        // align-items: stretch;
      
            h3 {
            color: white;
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }
       
        .item {
            
            flex: 1;

            img {
                height: 10rem;
                width: auto;
                display: block;
                margin: auto;
                margin-bottom: 2rem;
                opacity: .40;
                transition: 1s;

                    // &:hover {
                    //     opacity: 1.0;
                    // }
            }
            
            h3 {
                padding-top: 2rem;
                transition-duration: .5s;

               
            }
        }
                .item:hover  img {
                    opacity: 1.0;
                }
               .item:hover h3 {
                padding-top: 0rem;
                transition-duration: .5s;
                }
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks but I want to hover to start as soon as it goes over the black background for that section.

Comment: That’s why I was trying to make .items or . Item to be 100% of its parent.